# How to import an Excel file into MySQL using ODBC in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, odbc, import-from-excel

I want to import an Excel file into a MySQL database using an ODBC driver. Does Java support this technique? If yes, please guide me on how to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read an Excel file in Java using the Apache POI library: http://poi.apache.org/
There are some code samples on their howto page which will tell you how to read an Excel file: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html

To store the data it would be better for you to use the JDBC driver for MySQL rather than ODBC since ODBC relies on native libraries. You can get the connector here: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

If you absolutely must use ODBC, then you can see how to do that here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/bridge.html

Comment: I have 200,000 records in the xls file, rather than reading one-by-one i want to import that file in database, is this possible by connectors and how?

Comment: You will need to read the file first, and then store the data you want to keep in the database. The connector is the library that allows you to store data in the database.