# Is there any API that takes an Excel file and converts it to a CSV file using Java?

Tags: java, excel, csv

I have 200,000 or more records in an Excel file.  If I tried to read records row by row and create a CSV file it's very costly as well as time consuming.  Is there any API that can help me with that?

Comment: Why would you want do all the trouble of using Java when you can just "Save As CSV" from Excel?

Comment: Because what i am going to implemnt, there will not be any manual work. All things i have to program.

Comment: try solution provided in [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jexcel/converting-excel-documents-to-csv-files.html).

Comment: @Harry Joy: To my knowledge jxl only supports xls files, not xlsx.

Comment: @Harry This is to read one by one row, I am looking that it could be directly converted to csv or imported to mySQl with iterating each row

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to import excel file in mysql using odbc in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516705/how-to-import-excel-file-in-mysql-using-odbc-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several frameworks out there, if you have a look.

For example, you can try:

- Apache POI ([example](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html))
- JExcel ([example](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jexcel/converting-excel-documents-to-csv-files.html))

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same question as [How to import an Excel file into MySQL using ODBC in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516705/how-to-import-excel-file-in-mysql-using-odbc-in-java/6516844)

What has changed? If you want to write to a CSV file you should use a CSV library such as OpenCSV: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Given link said to read one by one row of xlsx and write to csv. I am looking for a tool that can be use through program to convert xls or xlsx to csv. I am converting xls or xlsx to csv because i found the way to import csv file to mysql.

Comment: How would you be able to convert the file without reading each row in it? Outputting to CSV is not going to be easier than writing directly to the database, but you would probably be able to create a solution quickly with the libraries I gave you.

Comment: so can i directly write xlsx to mysql without reading row by row

Comment: Any library that could do this would have to read your xlsx file row by row. Is it because you don't want to implement that yourself?

Comment: @Mathias No I can but I think it will be time taking and can slow down the system if number of records in millions

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/966/discussion-between-sam-and-mathias-schwarz)

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/980/discussion-between-sam-and-mathias-schwarz)