# How to read data from Excel spreadsheet and store into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, excel

I have a requirement in Java (Spring) to read data from an Excel spreadsheet and store it in MySQL database. More specifically, I have to read one row of data from an Excel spreadsheet every 5 minutes and store it to a MySQL database.

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516705/how-to-import-excel-file-in-mysql-using-odbc-in-java

Comment: This appears to be very similiar to [3621798](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621798) or [8031193](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031193)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mathias Schwarz wrote:

You can read an Excel file in Java using the Apache POI library: http://poi.apache.org/
There are some code samples on their howto page which will tell you how to read an Excel file: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html

To store the data you can use the JDBC driver for MySQL. You can get the connector here: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: thanks for giving answers this is what i'm looking for.